# Open Xen Manager and XenCenter server connection

Tags: debian, xen, remote-access

So, I've got server set up and running the Xen hypervisor version 4.1 with Debian Wheezy (7.5.0) as the host OS, along with xcp-xapi and all relevant services are running correctly. Problems arise when I try to connect to the server through Open Xen Manager or XenCenter.

Open Xen Manager gives me this error message:

```
[Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

XenCenter gives me this error message:

```
Unable to connecto server '192.168.178.21'
The connection was refused.

Check that XenServer is configured correctly on '192.168.178.21' and try again.
```

And I also get a

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

error if I use the locally installed Open Xen Manager.

I'm able to connect to the server over SSH. Using Open Xen Manager rev48 and XenCenter 6.2.

I'm at a loss as to what to try to solve this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out my problem. An IP conflict. :( Wonderful.